# get specific element from List C#

Tags: c#

I'd like to know if there is any method to get specific element from list for example

//if A.Nr=15 get directly b.Nr=15 and not b.Nr to look 1,2,3,...

Please see code snippet below, the comment explains what I'd like to do.
I hope anyone can help me.

```
    private void btnFind_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<Excel> lrez = new List<Excel>();
        var query = from li in listIndex
                    where li.Value == int.Parse(txtValue.Text)
                    select li;
        List<Excel> lresult = new List<Excel>();
        lresult = query.ToList();
        LinkedList<LinkList> linkedList = new LinkedList<LinkList>();
        for (int i = 0; i < lrsult.Count; i++)
        {
            LinkList a = new LinkList();
            Node A = new Node();
            A.Data = lresult[i].Nr;
            A.Nr = lresult[i].Nr;
            a.AddNode(A);
            linkedList.AddLast(a);

            Excel ex = lista.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Nr == A.Nr);
    //if A.Nr=15 get directly b.Nr=15 and not b.Nr to look 1,2,3,...                
    lrez.Add(ex);

        }
        dgvRez.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dgvRez.DataSource = lrezultati;
}
```

Comment: for that use Dictionary

Comment: You're talking about finding elements in a list and the first code I see is related to databases. Could you please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) instead?

Comment: Could you please reduce your code sample to what is needed to understand your question? I am not opposed to extensive code samples, if they make sense - but I *think* that we are just talking about a single line here, right?

Comment: Your example isn't particularly clear - could you give more detail on how you want to select items (and preferably reduce the amount of code posted)

Comment: It is very difficult to tell what exactly you're asking. Please try rephrasing the question.

Comment: I have 3 lists, first is filled from excel, second is filled from first ordered by value. third list should be filled from first one where value in first is equal to value in second . And I used linked list to do this, but I have the problem shown in my question because I can't get specific element from first list without looking other elements. I hope I was clear.

Answer (score 2):

Try using LINQ:

```
Excel result = lista.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Nr == 15);
```

This will return null if such an item cannot be found.